# Cross entropy loss: inconsistency in formula

Tags: cross-entropy

I have a couple of problems trying to understand the exact formula for cross entropy loss. Depending on the source I see it written different ways.

- Is the log() function $\log_2()$?
- Is the argument in the log: $q$ or $1/q$?

I am fairly certain it is $\log_2$ and $1/q$ but the variants worry me.

Why am I seeing it different ways?  Could someone not only confirm my understanding but also suggest why there are so many variants out there?

Comment: The base of the log is not important in many applications. For example, in model comparison, changing the base of the log will not change the ordering of the cross-entropy or the K-L divergences. $\log_2$ is used where expressing the information in bits is convenient, while $\ln$ is often used as it is easier to deal with it mathematically.

With regard to the second question, $\log(p) = -\log(1/p)$. So, I would check for a minus sign in the variants.

Comment: Perfect. Feel free to make this an answer and I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base of the log is not important in many applications. For example, in model comparison, changing the base of the log will not change the ordering of the cross-entropy or the K-L divergences. $\log_2$ is used where expressing the information in bits is convenient, while $\ln$ is often used as it is easier to deal with it mathematically.

With regard to the second question, $\log(p)=−\log(1/p)$. So, I would check for a minus sign in the variants.